# React: Display hierarchical JSON data in a collapsable table

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, material-ui, react-bootstrap

I have the following hierarchical JSON data. I want to display it in a table that is collapsible and hierarchical. Which React UI framework/plugin supports display hierarchical data with [slide bar for the "volume"](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwix4qb7q__fAhXhMewKHdoEDh4QjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjqueryplugins.net%2Fbootstrap-slider-plugin%2F&psig=AOvVaw20qBURy_0Kpwg3Qf1LRzer&ust=1548176196652777) field? How do I implement it?

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "a",
        "another": [
        {
            "anotherId": 2,
            "anotherName": "Content1",
            "format": [
            {
                "format": "format1",
                "isEnabled": true,
                "volume": 8
            },
            {
                "format": "format2",
                "isEnabled": true,
                "volume": 6
            }
            ]
        },
        {
            "anotherId": 3,
            "anotherName": "Content2",
            "format": [
            {
                "format": "format4",
                "isEnabled": true,
                "volume": 13
            },
            {
                "format": "format5",
                "isEnabled": true,
                "volume": 20
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "b",
        "another": [
        {
            "anotherId": 6,
            "anotherName": "Content6",
            "format": [
            {
                "format": "format6",
                "isEnabled": true,
                "volume": 7
            },
            {
                "format": "format6",
                "isEnabled": false,
                "volume": 0
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is How I want the data to be displayed.

```
1              a
 2              Content1
    format1         true        -------8-------------
    format2         true        -----6---------------
 3              Content2
    format4         true        ------------13-------
    format5         true        --------------------20
2              b
 6             Content6
    format6         true        ------7--------------
    format7         false       0--------------------
```

Comment: the way you want to display data looks a mess :) I recommend https://github.com/mac-s-g/react-json-view#implementation-example

Comment: I want a UI framework. The way I wanted to show data is using a table or div that is collapsible and extendable when you click on the parent row. I tried using collapse from `reactstrap` but working with deeper hierarchies is challenging

Answer (score 1):

Here is a framework-less approach that uses a table format.  If you use a ui framework like bootstrap, you can just use their classNames.  [Here's a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pwpqjk76jx) that uses a module called `react-collapsible` to do the collapsing.

```
export default function Test(props) {

var fmtd = dta.map((la, idx) => {
    var fmt1 = la.another.map((lb, idx2) => {
        return(
    <div key = {idx2}>    
        <tr style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}} >
            <td style={{paddingRight: 10, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold'}}> {la.id}</td><td style={{paddingLeft: 10, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold'}}> {la.name}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
            <td style={{paddingRight: 10, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold'}}> {lb.anotherId}</td><td style={{paddingLeft: 10, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold'}}> {lb.anotherName}</td>
        </tr>
        { lb.format.map((lc, idx3) => {
            let volBar = []
            for(let i = 0; i <21; i++){
                i === lc.volume ? volBar.push(lc.volume) : volBar.push("-")
            }
        return(
        <tr key={idx3}style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
            <td style={{paddingRight: 10, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold'}}> 
                {lc.format}
            </td>
            <td style={{paddingLeft: 10, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold'}}> 
            {lc.isEnabled}
            </td>
            <td style={{paddingLeft: 10, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold'}}> 
            {volBar}
            </td>
        </tr>)
        })}
    </div>)
    })
        return (      
         <table>
            <tbody>
            {fmt1}
            </tbody>
         </table>

        )
})
return fmtd
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Though, I don't see `Collapsible` being used anywhere except `import` statement. Plus, I want the volume to be displayed in slider bar (https://jqueryplugins.net/bootstrap-slider-plugin/). I used dash (-) to represent the sliderbar.